# Plugin Compatibility test

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have developed a plugin for WordPress and it is working great with latest WordPress version 4.6.1 but I am afraid how can I check it is compatible for how older version or do I need any correction for older versions.

Do I need to download and install all version and test one by one, is there any shortcut or online solution?

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: are you asking,Any plugin to check wordpress theme backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the one have say @Vasmin [Better Plugin Compatibility Control](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/better-plugin-compatibility-control/)
But I'm not sure if is what you ask. I don't think can tell you which issues could have with the old version.

Maybe the best for you it's try the old and see if your plug-in still work. [Here there are all](https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/)

Comment: Good luck, will be a long work! but probably you can test only the big update and jump the x.x.1 that are small changes and usually are for correct small security bug in Wordpress core.

Answer (score 0):

Have a glance at Better Plugin Compatibility Control. I just found this out this morning. I think this does what you're after.

Have a glance at https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-plugin-compatibility-control/.  I think this does what you're after.